# Is it possible to implement IPSec with failover between one pfSense firewall and Amazon VPC (no BGP)

Tags: failover, pfsense, vpc

I'm trying to create a VPN connexion between my firewall (a pfsense 2.0.1) and my Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC). Amazon provides two peers endpoints to mount two IPsec tunnels on the same VPC.

At this moment, I'm able to mount an IPSec tunnel between my public IP and one of the Amazon endpoints.
The idea is to avoid a "disconnection" on Amazon side in case of the main tunnel fails and to switch on a backup tunnel (failover on our side is managed with CARP).

I'm trying to mount two IPsec tunnels on the same pfsense gateway (one public IP), just like the following graph:
[image: a VPC]

Is it possible to do so with pfSense?

[image: a VPC]

The full scenario with a cisco router example is available here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/Cisco_NoBGP.html

Thank you in advance for your help,

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think it possible : 
Pfsense doc : Both locations must be using non-overlapping LAN IP subnets.
And no "ip virtual-reassembly" seen.

btw, pfsense 2.0.1 is outdated, and more recent support IPSec+L2TP